# Как в php явно указать тип данных (собственный т.е класса)

Tags: php

Нужно в метод передать тип `Publication`. Но как явно указать тип переменой класса в метод send?

```
 private $post;
    public function __construct(Publication $post)
    {
        $this->$post=$post;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      Notify::send($this->post);

    }
}
```

Comment: Не считая мелких ошибок, на которые вам указали в ответе, вы уже определили тип $post. Конструктор класса явно ожидает Publication $post и в любом случае пыха вам скажет, если туда будет приходить что-то кроме. Таким образом, private $post в любом варианте будет Publication

Answer (score 3):

Для php 7.4

```
private Publication $post;
```

для версий ниже 7.4 через анотации

```
/**
 * @var Publication
 */
private $post;
```

Так же в конструкторе у вас ошибка присвоения переменной, должно быть так:

```
$this->post = $post;
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\LogicLayer\Notify::send() must be an instance of App\Publication, null given

Comment: у вас ошибка

$this->post=$post;

вместо 
$this->$post=$post;

Comment: какая ошибка там?

Comment: $this->$post - перед post не нужен знак доллара. Это некорректное обращение к переменной класса.